# Why left join on CriteriaQuery doesn't filter results?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have two entities, `User` and `Roles` each one with active boolean parameter and `ManyToMany` relationship.

*This boolean parameter is used for logical delete.*

Why does the result include inactive Roles when I run this query below?

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);

 //Select
 Root<User> user = query.from(User.class);

 //Join
 SetJoin<User, Role> role = user.joinSet("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
 Predicate rolesActivePredicate = builder.isTrue(role.get("active"));
 role.on(rolesActivePredicate);

 query.multiselect(user).distinct(true);

 //Where
 Predicate usernamePredicate = builder.equal(user.get("username"), username);
 Predicate activePredicate = builder.isTrue(user.get("active"));
 query.where(usernamePredicate, activePredicate);

 TypedQuery<UnikUser> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
 return Optional.of(typedQuery.getSingleResult());
```

Comment: If you don't have strong reasons for suspecting the issue is caused by jpa 2.2, you should use the `jpa` tag instead, in order to attract more answers. For the same reason, you should add the `criteria-api` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider the following `User`s with `@OneToMany` relationship to `Role`s.

```
 User-1 : Active-Role-1, Active-Role-2, In-Active-Role-3
 User-2 : In-Active-Role-3
 User-3 : Active-Role-1, Active-Role-2
```

2. JPA first finds `User` records that satisfy your condition (have at-least one an active role)

```
 User-1
 User-3
```

3. **This is where the role of your where conditions end**. Once it has been decided which record id to fetch, JPA will fetch those `User` records in full. `User-1` and `User-3` with all their associated roles (including inactive). It might do `join` or another `select` but whenever it does, it will fetch all of its associated fields
4. In summary, Once it has decided to fetch an `entity`, **it cannot do any filtering on its associated fields**. In this case, you expected a filtered objects in `user.getRoles()` but it cannot.
5. If JPA had allowed that, it cannot do `dirty checking`, `cascading` or `repeatable read`. So it does not allow it

Comment: Gotcha! Is there and alternative to avoid this inactive results?

Comment: well. You know you have the right users. So when you create `userDto`, why don't you do the filtering? i.e when mapping user to userDto, you can create a custom mapper called  `UserToUserWithActiveRolesDtoMapper` and then do your filtering in memory. Or you have to write queries that select columns and use row mapper to create objects

Comment: I don't have reputation for it.