# Hibernate: is it possible to retrieve only children matching a condition?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following one to many:

```
public class EntityA{
 ...
private List<EntityB> entities;
}
```

where entity b has:

```
public class EntityB{
     ...
     private String type;
}
```

Now, I do my queries on the entityA, for example:

```
@Query("select a from EntityA a where a.field= :field)
```

Would it  be possible to have the whole A entity but only the children whose "type" is equal to a specific one?
I tried doing:

```
@Query("select a from EntityA a where a.field= :field and a.entities.type in ('A', 'B'))
```

but this leads to zero results, while my intention is to retrieve the entity A with an empty list.

Comment: It is not possible unless you retrieve the object as scaler object . See this answer here to see why JPA cannot do that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659001/why-left-join-on-criteriaquery-doesnt-filter-results/62660891#62660891

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is bi-directional or you can make it bi-directional, then you can Query it from `EntityB` side:

```
@Query("select b.entityA from EntityB b where b.type in ('A', 'B')")
public Set<EntityA> aEntities();
```