# Join Fetch with conditions on the right table

Tags: spring, jpa, fetch, hql

Suppose I have a OneToMany relationship:

- Parent is the parent entity
- Child is the child entity

Now I want to find the parent by id in JpaRepository but I want only the children ( which are lazy loaded ) that have a certain attribute isActive true. I have tried specifying this in a @Query like this:

```
FROM PARENTS P JOIN FETCH P.children P WHERE P.id = :id AND P.children.isActive is true.
```

But it dosen't return anything ( the database has data that should be returned )
Can I achieve this in a single query or should I just write another query that returns the requested children ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you paste the sql query that you use to check whether the data to be returned exists?

Comment: I have no sql query but I think this should work:
SELECT * FROM PARENTS INNER JOIN CHILDREN on CHILDREN.ownerId = PARENTS.id AND CHILDREN.isActive is true

Comment: And if you run this, then you get the results? With this part: `P.id = :id`

Comment: Yes the result is correct, just tried it now in PGAdmin, the P.id = :id is from JPA it just replaces the :id with the id given as parameter

Comment: You cannot do that in JPA. Here I have explained for for User and Roles. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659001/why-left-join-on-criteriaquery-doesnt-filter-results/62660891#62660891 . i.e your condition only decides which Parents to select. I.e a parent with at least one active children. Once it is decided which parent to select, ALL THE CHILDREN of that parent will be selected by JPA for the reasons explained in the answer

Comment: FROM PARENTS P JOIN FETCH P.children P WHERE P.id = :id AND P.children.isActive = true. I managed to do it like this actually and it's kinda working, but it does not fetch the users with inactive children.