# Problem with querying entities with a set of entities in Spring Boot @Query

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a Spring Boot `@Query` in JpaRepository which returns me entities with a set of other entities. I know that I can use `findAll()` method, and then take only those rows that I'm interested in, but I think that this is much slower. The problem is that my entity `Booster` contains a `Set` of other entities `Boost`, and when i try to query it, I get an error. So, this is my `Query`:

```
    @Query( "select new app.model.Booster(" +
            "   B.id, " +
            "   B.active, " +
            "   B.games, " +
            "   B.ownerAccount, " +
            "   B.boosts, " +
            "   B.boosterNickname, " +
            "   B.additionalInformation) " +
            "from " +
            "   Booster B " +
            "   left join Boost Bo on B.id = Bo.boostingAccount.id " +
            "where " +
            "   B.games like %?1% " +
            "   and Bo.finished = true " +
            "group by " +
            "   B.id")
    List<Booster> findBoostersForOverview(String game);
```

These are my entity classes:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Booster")
public class Booster {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private boolean active;
    private String games;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "boosterAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Account ownerAccount;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "boostingAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Boost> boosts;
    private String boosterNickname;
    private String additionalInformation;
```

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Boost")
public class Boost {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
    private long id;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date dateFinished;
    private Date dateLastModification;
    private boolean finished;
    private boolean paused;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boosted_account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account boostedAccount;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "boosting_account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Booster boostingAccount;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "boost", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Game> games;
    private String game;
    private String additionalInformation;
    private String server;
```

This is what console shows:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        booster0_.id as col_0_0_,
        booster0_.active as col_1_0_,
        booster0_.games as col_2_0_,
        booster0_.id as col_3_0_,
        . as col_4_0_,
        booster0_.booster_nickname as col_5_0_,
        booster0_.additional_information as col_6_0_ 
    from
        booster booster0_ 
    //HERE IS SOME MORE LOGS THAT ARE UNNECESSARY HERE
```

And this is error i get:
`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_4_0_, booster0_.booster_nickname as col_5_0_, booster0_.additional_info' at line 1`
I know that I can query without `Set` of `Boost`, and then in another query get specific `Boost`s, but in my app there will be a lot of SQL and my code will turn to spaghetti. Is there a simple way to solve my problem?

Comment: Is `Booster` and `Boost` entities related? If so can you add the `Boost` entity class to your question? And is there a difference between classes  `app.model.Booster` and `Booster` that is being saved?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I added entity classes to code. I don't understand what you mean by "And is there a difference between classes app.model.Booster and Booster that is being saved?", but there is no other class Booster, taht app.model.Booster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the following to your repository **without** any `@Query` annotation and see?

```
    List<Booster> findByGamesLikeAndBoostsFinishedIsTrue(String game);
```

Comment: I totally forgot, that queries in JPA can be created this way. It works, but not the way i want it to work. It returns the same Booster multiple times, as Booster has a Set of Boost's and each time it finds a Boost that is finished and belongs to a given Booster, it returns it. Is there a way to return a Booster with only finished Boost's, or I have to do int manyally in BoostserService?

Comment: Above query is for `return any Booster where at least one of its boost is finished` .Is your  requirement differ? If so, is it 1)  `return any Booster where all of its boost is finished?`  2) `return any Booster where at least one of its boost is finished but when returning that booster remove any other unfinished boosts from it children`?

Comment: A query i wanted to get is `return any Booster for a given game with all it's finished Boost`.

Comment: so if the Booster for given game had some unfinished Boosts, you don't want them to be included in `booster.getBoosts()`?

Comment: For this particular query - yes. And i want to know, if i have get the entire `Set` of `Boost` as a result, and then remove unfinished one, or if there is a way to do it with the query.

Comment: You will not be able to do that JPQL  as it breaks the basics of hibernates fundamentals of  `repeatable read`, `dirty-checking` and `transactional-write-behind`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659001/why-left-join-on-criteriaquery-doesnt-filter-results/62660891#62660891

Comment: Thanksm  it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, you are using `GROUP BY`. When you are using `Group By` you have use aggregate functions `(COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG)` to group the result-set by one or more columns in the select column. Aggregate functions are **mandatory** when using `GROUP BY` function.

In your case, I hope `Group By` is not required. Modify your code like below.

```
@Query( "select new app.model.Booster(" +
        "   B.id, " +
        "   B.active, " +
        "   B.games, " +
        "   B.ownerAccount, " +
        "   B.boosts, " +
        "   B.boosterNickname, " +
        "   B.additionalInformation) " +
        "from " +
        "   Booster B " +
        "   left join Boost Bo on B.id = Bo.boostingAccount.id " +
        "where " +
        "   B.games like %?1% " +
        "   and Bo.finished = true")
List<Booster> findBoostersForOverview(String game);
```

Comment: Aggregate functions are not mandatory when using GROUP BY. SELECT a, b, c FROM some_table GROUP BY a, b, c; is a perfectly normal way of getting all unique combinations of a, b & c from some_table.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right. Forgot to remove this line after i changed this query from it's previous version. The problem is, that even after I applied a change to my code, error still occurs.

Comment: Oops! Anyway, you got a solution! I am happy bro.